# AngularJS - How to call a service in a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller here that calls a service, it works fine, however I needed to call a method that is inside that service in another module. How can I do this?

BaSiderbarService:

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components')
      .provider('baSidebarService', baSidebarServiceProvider);

  /** @ngInject */
  function baSidebarServiceProvider() {




    var staticMenuItems = [];

    this.addStaticItem = function() {
      staticMenuItems.push.apply(staticMenuItems, arguments);
    };

    /** @ngInject */
    this.$get = function($state, layoutSizes) {
      return new _factory();

      function _factory() {
        var isMenuCollapsed = shouldMenuBeCollapsed();

        this.getMenuItems = function() {
          var states = defineMenuItemStates();
          var menuItems = states.filter(function(item) {
            return item.level == 0;
          });

          menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
            var children = states.filter(function(child) {
              return child.level == 1 && child.name.indexOf(item.name) === 0;
            });
            item.subMenu = children.length ? children : null;
          });

          return menuItems.concat(staticMenuItems);
        };

        this.shouldMenuBeCollapsed = shouldMenuBeCollapsed;
        this.canSidebarBeHidden = canSidebarBeHidden;

        this.setMenuCollapsed = function(isCollapsed) {
          isMenuCollapsed = isCollapsed;
        };

        // I need call this method in another controller    
        this.getStorage = function(){
            console.log(localStorage.user);
        }

        this.isMenuCollapsed = function() {
          return isMenuCollapsed;
        };

        this.toggleMenuCollapsed = function() {
          isMenuCollapsed = !isMenuCollapsed;
        };

        this.getAllStateRefsRecursive = function(item) {
          var result = [];
          _iterateSubItems(item);
          return result;

          function _iterateSubItems(currentItem) {
            currentItem.subMenu && currentItem.subMenu.forEach(function(subItem) {
              subItem.stateRef && result.push(subItem.stateRef);
              _iterateSubItems(subItem);
            });
          }
        };

        function defineMenuItemStates() {
          return $state.get()
              .filter(function(s) {
                return s.sidebarMeta;
              })
              .map(function(s) {
                var meta = s.sidebarMeta;
                return {
                  name: s.name,
                  title: s.title,
                  level: (s.name.match(/\./g) || []).length,
                  order: meta.order,
                  icon: meta.icon,
                  stateRef: s.name,
                };
              })
              .sort(function(a, b) {
                return (a.level - b.level) * 100 + a.order - b.order;
              });
        }

        function shouldMenuBeCollapsed() {
          return window.innerWidth <= layoutSizes.resWidthCollapseSidebar;
        }

        function canSidebarBeHidden() {
          return window.innerWidth <= layoutSizes.resWidthHideSidebar;
        }
      }

    };

  }
})();
```

This is the module I need to inject the service and call the method I need DashboardModule:

```
    /**
 * @author v.lugovsky
 * created on 16.12.2015
 */


(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard', [])
        .config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {

        // I need call service here
        baSidebarService.getStorage()

        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                title: 'Dashboard',
                resolve: {
                   user: function(baSidebarService){ 

                console.log('DASHBOARD',baSidebarService.getStorage())
                }
            },
                sidebarMeta: {
                    icon: 'ion-android-home',
                    order: 0,
                },
            });
    }

})();
```

Is there any way to do this? I need to get this method so I can make a logic over that value

Comment: make resolver instead

Comment: How can I do this? I did not understand

Comment: do you want to call a method that is inside a service?

Comment: Yes, I applied the resolver, but I do not know how to call out of the state to be able to do logic

Comment: I edit the code

Comment: so basically you want to call service when module load right ?? not when route call?

Comment: Yes, when it is loaded, why do I need to apply a logic before the $ stateprovider

Comment: @pal can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the service:

```js
    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($stateProvider, baSidebarService) {

        // I need call service here
        baSidebarService.getStorage()
```